# Let $f ∶ Z × Z → Z × Z$ be defined as $f(m, n) = (3m + 7n, 2m + 5n)$. Is f a bijection, i.e. oneto-one and onto?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

It seems obvious that it is one to one because $f(m,n)$ contains linear equations so it would seem intuitive to say that $f(m,l) = f(n,k)$ then $m=n$ and $l=k$, but there is probably another way of proving it. Also I need to prove that it is unto but that comes back to saying that the pair of functions are linear and so for any $n$ and $m$ combination, you get a different pair as a result. Could you confirm or give a hint to solving it in a more appropriate way?

Answer (score 2):

You can write this equation system by

$$f(\pmatrix{m\\n})=\pmatrix{3&7\\2&5}\cdot \pmatrix{m\\n}$$

Because of $$\det(\pmatrix{3&7\\2&5})=1$$ the map is bijective. The inverse map is given by

$$f^{-1}(\pmatrix{m\\n})=\pmatrix{5&-7\\-2&3}\cdot \pmatrix{m\\n}$$

Comment: Wow, that was simple. Thanks

Comment: Every linear map can be represented by a matrix-multiplication. This way, it is easy to calculate the inverse map (if existent)

Comment: But if the determinants wasn't 1, then I would have to multiply all the terms of the inverse map matrix by 1/D, right?

Comment: Yes, we only have a bijective map if the determinant is a unit of $\mathbb Z$ : $\pm1$

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**: the function is indeed bijective. To show injectivity: demonstrate the following implication:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{lr}3m_1+7n_1&=3m_2+7n_2\\
2m_1+5n_1&=2m_2+5n_2
\end{array}\right.\implies (m_1,n_1)=(m_2,n_2).
$$
To show surjectivity, demonstrate the following claim:
$$
\forall x,y\in\mathbb{Z}:\quad\exists\;m,n\quad\text{  s.t. }\quad 3m+7n=x, 2m+5n=y.
$$
For this latter claim, the end result looks something like
$$
m=5x-\ldots y,\quad n=-\cdots x+3y.
$$